# Privacy Policy question

Tags: united-kingdom, privacy

Can I use the pen name as the full name of the legal entity on the privacy policy of my new author website (I'm using my christian name and mother's maiden name as my pen name). I'm UK based. Thanks

Comment: You must provide your identity and contact details. A pseudonym is likely sufficient to clarify who's running the website. [EDPB guidance](https://ec.europa.eu/newsroom/article29/item-detail.cfm?item_id=622227) states: “This information should allow for easy identification of the controller and preferably allow for different forms of communications with the data controller (e.g. phone number, email, postal address, etc.)”.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

Anything you use to identify yourself is your “name”. Except in specific situations (e.g. your passport) it doesn’t have to be your registered name.